# How to rotate an SSE/AVX vector

Tags: c, x86, sse, intrinsics, avx

I need to perform a rotate operation with as little clock cycles as possible.
In the first case let's assume `__m128i` as source and dest type:

```
source: || A0 || A1 || A2 || A3 ||
```

```
  dest: || A1 || A2 || A3 || A0 ||
```

```
dest = (__m128i)_mm_shuffle_epi32((__m128i)source, _MM_SHUFFLE(0,3,2,1));
```

Now I want to do the same with AVX intrinsics.
So let's assume this time `__m256i` as source and dest type:

```
source: || A0 || A1 || A2 || A3 || A4 || A5 || A6 || A7 ||
```

```
  dest: || A1 || A2 || A3 || A4 || A5 || A6 || A7 || A0 ||
```

The AVX intrinsics is missing most of the corresponding SSE integer operations.
Maybe there is some way go get the desired output working with the floating point version.

I've tried with:

```
dest = (__m256i)_mm256_shuffle_ps((__m256)source, (__m256)source, _MM_SHUFFLE(0,3,2,1));
```

but what I get is:

```
|| A0 || A2 || A3 || A4 || A5 || A6 || A7 || A1 ||
```

Any Idea on how to solve this in an efficient way? (without mixing SSE and AVX operation and without "manually" inverting `A0` and `A1`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't have much experience with SSE and AVX, but in the second line of code, if dest type is `__m256`, why are you casting to `__m128i`?

Comment: Of course it was __m256i, thanks!

Comment: No I just went wrong with cut&paste..

Comment: Seems like all the useful instructions are in AVX2 (why didn't they release that one *first*?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My solution:

```
__m256 tmp =  ( __m256 ) _mm256_permute_ps((__m256)_source, _MM_SHUFFLE ( 0,3,2,1 ));
* ( _dest ) =  ( __m256i) _mm256_blend_ps(tmp, _mm256_permute2f128_ps ( tmp,tmp,1 ), 136);
```

Comment: Any chance of an explanation of the 2 immediates your passing in on the second line? (1 and 136) I've read the docs, but am still not understanding why these particular values are what you want for this.

Comment: @OrvidKing: `permute2f128(tmp,tmp,1)` swaps the upper and lower 128b lanes.  136 = 0x88 = take the high element from one vector, other elements from the other (so, 0x8 in each lane, because `blendps` uses the two halves of the `imm8` for the two lanes.)

Answer (score 3):

I have not yet checked how things are with AVX, but at least for SSE, did you consider `_mm_align*`?

For instance, this rotates a byte vector by 2 bytes:

```
__m128i v;
v = _mm_alignr_epi8 (v, v, 2) // v = v[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,0,1]
```

This can be a single instruction. Also such operations are lat 1 / tp 1, i.e. fast.

AVX is likely a bit of a hassle with this approach, so an adaptation may not be useful.